# How to exclude strings that end in any number when using COUNTIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I have a table and I want to count the number of times a string appears on a column. I used `COUNTIF` to do this, but I want to exclude in the count those cells with strings ending in any number.

I tried using this formula but the criteria is unrecognized as it always erroneously gives a value of 0:

```
=COUNTIF([Name],"*"&A3&NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT("*")))))
```

EDIT:

The screenshot below shows I want to count how many times `Area 25` appears on column `Name`,
including `San Jose Area 25` (since it contains the substring `Area 25`)
but NOT `San Jose Area 252` and `Area 251` (since these strings end in numbers AFTER the string `Area 25`), and NOT `Area 25-A` either (since `Area 25` is connected with another substring `-A`:

[image: Excel COUNTIF error]

So the result I want to see in Cell D3 is **4**, which are:
`Area 25` (cells A3 and A11),
`Area 25 Zone B` (cell A4), and
`San Jose Area 25` (cell A8).

Comment: Something like this should work:  `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(G1:G10)))))`.  I wasn't able to test this with a named table/column, though

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thanks for the response, but what I am trying to achieve is to count how many times a string (like "Area 25") occurs in a column.

Comment: Yes, that's what this formula does, except I thought you wanted to *exclude* cells that end with a number - like Area 25.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Sorry for being confusing. I have added a screenshot and added some details. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: If it can be assumed that what you are looking for ends with "Area 25" or has "Area 25"+space+additional, then try this: =SUM(COUNTIFS(A21:A11,{"*Area 25","*Area 25 *"})) If you are not familiar an array can be used to capture note all of the alternatives, then the sum is counting each answer from the array.

Comment: @gns100 Thanks, the formula works. Is it possible to use references (A2, A3) in the array instead of text since I would want to fill the column with that formula. I tried doing this but it won't work: =SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,{"*"&A3,"*"A3&" *"}))

Comment: I'm pretty sure the array has to be statically declared in the formula. I've tried to put the array in a cell and then reference the cell, but couldn't get it to work. Maybe someone out there knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the "IF" part differently.

```
=COUNT(SEARCH("Area 25",IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A10,1)))),A1:A10,"")))
```

`RIGHT(something,1)` finds the last character of every STRING, then `VALUE()` tries to make it a number. `ISNUMBER()` tests the success of that, and `NOT()` reverses the TRUE/FALSE values found by it to be FALSE/TRUE.

`IF()` then uses those TRUE/FALSE results to decide how to branch, either returning the cell value or "". You are testing only those cells that met the test for not having a numeric digit as their last character.

`SEARCH()` looks through all of that, blanks and all, but importantly, those cells that still have values, for the content you are seeking. It will return the starting points of said string in each, so one can't simply `SUM()` the results. The error returns wouldn't make that easy either. However, the successes ARE numeric results, so a simple `COUNT()` finishes things off by counting them. It ignores anything not a number so it ignores the errors. It also counts a number as "1, each" so if the target string begins at character 37, hence a return of 37 for that cell, it still `COUNT()`'s simply as "1", not "37" so does what you want here.

At the time of the question, and now (2021), the range can be a Named Range allowing it to expand and contract without needing changed in the formula.

Now, if one WANTS to definitively see the range and be sure it's right without delving into the Named Ranges, one can use `LET()` to define the "named range" at the very beginning of the formula so it is easy to see and edit.